# Fetch columns with same name from json field in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a requirement where I have to select a city in two columns from the JSON where city exists with the key "City". The first value in the table is coming up as null, not able to find a possible solution

```
val jsonString="""{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PARC PARQUE","State":"PR"}"""
    val data = Seq((1, jsonString))
    import spark.implicits._
    val df=data.toDF("id","value")
    df.show(false)


    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructType}
    val schema = new StructType()
      .add("Zipcode", StringType, true)
      .add("ZipCodeType", StringType, true)
      .add("City", StringType, false)
      .add("City", StringType, true)


    val df4=df.withColumn("value",from_json(col("value"),schema))
    df4.printSchema()
    df4.show(false)

    val df5=df4.select(col("id"),col("value.*"))
    df5.printSchema()
    df5.show()
```

Actual Result:

```
| id|Zipcode|ZipCodeType|City|       City|

|  1|    704|   STANDARD|null|PARC PARQUE|
```

Expected Result:

```
| id|Zipcode|ZipCodeType|City|       City|

|  1|    704|   STANDARD|PARC PARQUE|PARC PARQUE|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating your problem here. Just use the spark inbuilt functions and you should be fine.

I would recommend using `spark.read.json` function to do your processing.
Here, is what i did.

```
val jsonStr = """{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PARC PARQUE","State":"PR"}"""

import spark.implicits._
val df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonStr).toDS) // this function has overloaded implementation as well so that you can also read json files directly from HDFS/S3

// if you do df.printSchema, it wonn't have a duplicate columns
df.printSchema
```

The output will look something like this. As you can see there is no duplicate City field
[image: output]

Comment: The thing is I don't want to fetch all the columns from the JSON. But yes this can be a possible solution if I select the desired columns from the dataframe. Thanks

Comment: @SofiaSehgal, JSON  follows a row based storage which means that you would read entire row as a whole. If you were to read only selected data, you would have to store the input data as parquet or ORC. However, as you said you can always ```drop``` the columns that you do not need.